# pivot-like calculation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
JID    SKID  VALUE
--------------------
alpha    a    6
alpha    b    3
alpha    c    2
beta     a    3
beta     b    5
gamma    a    1
gamma    c    3
...
```

(note there is no gamma/b)

I also have a test db that looks like this:

```
SKID   VALUE
a      3
b      4
c      2
```

What I am trying to do is for each JID in the first table, perform a calculation that is a sum of a function that uses (the VALUE for each SKID from the first table with the VALUE for each SKID from the second).

So the resulting table would have JID / SCORE as its headers, where SCORE is a complex (but describable) calculation.

pseudocode:

```
for each SKID in JID {
      TEMP = calculation(table1.Value, table2.value)
      SCORE = SCORE + TEMP
} 
RETURN JID, SCORE
```

I know I can do this in another language, but I would prefer to do the calculation straight in SQL, but I am not sure how to do it, or if it is even possible.

Would it be faster to do it in SQL or by sending it out to python?  Is there a better language?

Comment: Can you provide an example output for your given example input?

Comment: Confused:   your question says MySQL, but you've tagged Sql-server.   Which is correct?

Comment: Changed tags from SQL Server -> MySQL since that's most likely what the OP is actually using

Comment: I'm sure it can be done in the DB but what should the actual result be? Do you just want to sum up the skid values from tab1 and tab2 and group them by jid? Can you please describe the calculation and the output that should result?

Comment: The result for the example given is: alpha = (6*3+4*3+2*2) = 34, beta = (3*3 + 4*5) = 29, gamma = (1*3 + 3*2) = 9

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this:

```
select jid, sum(score) 
from(
    select t1.jid, t2.ivalue*t1.ivalue as score 
    from t1 
    join t2  on t1.skid = t2.skid
    ) 
as subtable group by jid
```